# Where does a war server on JBOSS Standalone see as its Home directory on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, jboss, jboss7.x

I am running JBOSS AS-7 on Centos 6.4 and running it in standalone mode. I have deployed a .war and everything is fine. I now want to start using AWS DynamoDB and it requires me to store a credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials

Now, I understand that the tilde (~) means 'Home directory' but I have no idea how to find out where the deployed .war sees as it's own home directory.

I 'THINK' that the Standalone.sh is being run by a user called jboss (a local user), but any way to confirm that would be helpful.

I am able to login as root.

I hope that is enough information, and any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you gone through the JBoss docs. Can you link to the appropriate section in the docs and let us know what parts you didn't understand?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thanks @CKIng - I've been experimenting with the details from here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/General+configuration+concepts but (1) that's for wildfly (I can't find an appropriate JBOSS AS7 equivalent) and also the data at here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html The issue I have is that if I mess around with the system variables on the host machine, it won't make it very portable if I try to move to a different VM/Hostr etc. I was hoping just to find the 'default' way by making sure I had the credentials file in the default place.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a lot of hacking around, I found the answer.... and here's how to find yours....
The code from here:
[here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/print-all-java-system-properties)

which at the time of writing was:

```
    Properties p = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = p.keys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
    String value = (String)p.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

Allowed me to get the dump of all the details I needed. Now look for:
jboss.home.dir:

which in my case was:
jboss.home.dir: /usr/local/jboss

And thus I could create a directory (.aws) and put my credentials file there. Sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As @jww says, this is wrong forum, but considering the ease of answer. . .

I assume you installed jboss via yum instead of downloading it yourself. From the command line, while jboss is running, enter:

```
 ps -ef | grep jboss
```

or

```
 ps -ef | grep java
```

You should be able to note the user running the process from the results. It is indeed likely that there is a jboss user you can su to if you installed via yum.

Some good tutorials that would've served you better to read instead of ask us:

[Installing JBoss 7.1.1.Final on CentOS 6.x](http://www.opensourcearchitect.co/resources/tutorials/installing-jboss-7-1-on-centos-6)

[Installing and setting-up JAVA & JBoss 7 Final on a CentOS 6 Linux VPS](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/installing-and-setting-up-java-jboss-7-final-on-a-centos-6-linux-vps/)

They generally follow the same process and show you what the yum install probably is doing for you.

Comment: Thanks @Jon - I have upvoted this as it is helpful (but I don;t have enough rep to make a difference!)

Comment: All good, mate. Glad you found a way. If you do: more /etc/passwd and look for the JBoss user you may find it to point at /usr/local/jboss as well.